# Varianten der Ausdrücke „freilich" und „allerdings"

Tags: grammar, dialect, bavarian

In Bayern verwendet man oft "freilich" in Antworten auf mehr oder weniger selbstverständliche Fragen:

> Sprichst du Bayerisch?
>
> Ja, freilich/ allerdings!

Gibt es andere diesem Gebrauch entsprechende regional begrenzte Varianten in anderen Gegenden, zum Beispiel Nord- oder Ostdeutschland? Welche Varianten werden überregional verwendet?

Comment: I believe you should be able to find plenty of alternatives in a dictionary or a thesaurus.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht ganz. Ich glaub, hochdeutsch wäre: "Ja, sicher"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sicher, selbstverständig, natürlich, usw.